# VBA - defining range for multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Trying to define the same range `(A:WWW)` for each worksheet that is on a list in `Sheets("B").Range(C10:C42)` but below shown code is not working.

Sorry for not explaining the macro's objective well enough. Please let me try again here: The objective is to name 20 ranges from 20 worksheets. Example: There are 20 sheets, named apple, orange, grape, etc. This name list is in sheet "Background" in C1:C20, let's say. So... In Apple sheet: Name columns A:WWW as "Hist_Apple" In Orange sheet: Name columns A:WWW as "Hist_Orange" In Grape sheet: Name columns A:WWW as "Hist_Grape" Etc... for 20 times. Thank you for the quick response!!

```
Sub Define_Range()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim foundws As String

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

  Set foundws = Sheets("B").Range("C10:C42").Find(ws.Name, LookAt:=xlWhole)

  If foundws Is Nothing Then

    Sheets(foundws).Select

    With ActiveWindow
        Set rng = foundws.Range("$A:$WWW")
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Hist_" & foundws.Name, RefersTo:=rng
    End With

 End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: Edit the post and write exactly what you are trying to achieve !

Comment: Sorry for not explaining the macro's objective well enough. Please let me try again here:  The objective is to name 20 ranges from 20 worksheets.  Example:  There are 20 sheets, named apple, orange, grape, etc.  This name list is in sheet "Background" in C1:C20, let's say.  So...

In Apple sheet:  Name columns A:WWW as "Hist_Apple"
In Orange sheet:  Name columns A:WWW as "Hist_Orange"
In Grape sheet:  Name columns A:WWW as "Hist_Grape"
Etc... for 20 times.

Thank you for the quick response!!

Comment: Set rng = foundws.Range("$A:$WWW"): foundws is declared as string but u use it here as sheet. -> Set rng = .Sheets(foundws).Range("$A:$WWW")

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data, it is unclear, but consider replacing:

```
If foundws Is Nothing Then
```

with:

```
If Not foundws Is Nothing Then
```